# Pass envs to db via docker compose

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with passing envs via docker compose, below is my code:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose: 
      - '8080'
    command: npm run start
    environment: 
        MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        MYSQL_PORT: ${MYSQL_PORT}
        MYSQL_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_USERNAME}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.17-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN  npm build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start"]
```

db.config

```
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT ? +process.env.MYSQL_PORT : 3306,
      username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
```

i launch my docker-compose via `MYSQL_HOST= MYSQL_PORT= MYSQL_USERNAME= MYSQL_PASSWORD= MYSQL_DATABASE= docker-compose up -d`

why after successfully build my app, from docker consol of builded image i get an error like below:

```
[Nest] 36 - 05/05/2021, 6:03:46 PM [ExceptionHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 +2ms

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

I provide correct credentials like 'localhost`, 'root' etc. to the local db on xaamp, but this not work on docker :/

can someone tell me what is wrong?

thanks for any help!

Comment: you mean you fill in the values in `MYSQL_HOST= MYSQL_PORT= MYSQL_USERNAME= MYSQL_PASSWORD= MYSQL_DATABASE= docker-compose up -d` or you just put it like that?

Comment: i fill it e.q, `MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_PORT=3306 MYSQL_USERNAME=root MYSQL_PASSWORD= MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are telling it to find your myself at `localhost`, but from inside your container, `localhost` means the container itself, not your host system.

---

if you are *not* using linux, try `MYSQL_DATABASE=host.docker.internal`
(I haven't tried it)

If you *are* using linux, try `MYSQL_DATABASE=172.17.0.1`
(I just tried to curl my host and it totally works)

Comment: so, how should i fix?

Comment: I think this is worth a try: https://dev.to/natterstefan/docker-tip-how-to-get-host-s-ip-address-inside-a-docker-container-5anh